# Use pgfkeys to set a style variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I'd like to use pgfkeys to define the scale for a number of tikz pictures.  However, wenn I do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{/my special/variable/.code={.1}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale={/my special/variable}]
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get: `Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'my' (in '/my special/variable').`

`... [scale = \pgfkeys{/my special/variable}] ...` does not work, either.  LaTeX complains: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry`.

What's the right way to define a variable that can be used to set a style or other variable in TikZ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try some thing like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  myvar/.store in=\myvar,
  myvar=0.1,
   }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[myvar=2,scale={\myvar}]
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you don't give `myvar=2,`, the intial value (0.1) is used.

Comment: beat me by 4 secs!

Comment: +1, though I did not understand the need of doing this ;)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Just playing safe. :-)

Comment: Hmm.  Is there any benefit over `\newcommand{\myvar}{.2}`, then?

Comment: @JohannesBauer This is `tikz` way!

Comment: That doesn't do it for me.  It would at least have to keep the general LaTeX namespace clean to be worth the extra code clutter.  But I guess this is the correct answer to my question.  I'll accept.

Comment: @JohannesBauer: Honestly, here is not matter of keeping one philosophy or the other. The point here is that there is absolutely no need to define an extra key to manipulate one.

Comment: Not sure I get your meaning.  I'm doing this because I've got a large number of tikzpictures and I want them all to have the same adjustable scale.